# Confusion about cellular cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm confused about Hatcher's Theorem 3.5 on page 203. The theorem states:

$H^n(X;G) \approx$ ker$d_n/$ Im$d_{n-1}$. Furthermore, the cellular cochain complex $\{H^{n}(X^n,X^{n-1};G),d_n\}$ is isomorphic to the dual of the cellular chain complex, obtained by applying Hom$(-,G)$.

> I am particularly confused what it means for the cellular cochain complex to be isomorphic to the dual of the cellular chain complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is the cohomology complex with maps $$\delta:H^i(X^{i},X^{i-1}) \to H^{i+1}(X^{i+1},X^i)$$
and there is also the complex with maps $$d^*:\mathrm{Hom}(H_i(X),G) \to \mathrm{Hom}(H_{i+1}(X),G)$$
where $d^*(f)=f \circ d$.

To show an isomorphism, you want to exhibit a family of maps $$f_i:H^i(X^{i},X^{i-1}) \to \mathrm{Hom}(H_i(X),G)$$
where $f_{i+1} \circ \delta=d^* f_{i}$ (so that it commutes with the maps.)

Comment: I see, this makes sense. It's nice to have a proper definition in mathematics.

Comment: no problem. I think the problem is that this is quite deep into the book, and it this point Hatcher assumes the reader can work out the relevant statements, so he is pretty loose here. Glad to help!

Comment: I don't think this is a good choice on his part. I can make a guess as what the definition is, but having to guess definitions is not very satisfactory.

Comment: @Andres, Do you mean $\mathrm{Hom}(H_i(X^{i},X^{i-1}),G)$?

Answer (score 0):

Given a chain complex $(C_i(X), \partial_i)$, there are two ways to think of Cellular Co-Chain complex. The first way is by constructing the cellular chain complex $C^{Cell}_i(X) = H^i(X^{i},X^{i-1};\mathbb{Z})$ with boundary maps $D_i = j_{i-1} \circ \partial_i$, ie boundary maps induced by the provided boundary maps $\partial_i$. Now we could take take the cohomology with $G$ coefficients. So we would get $(C^{i}_{Cell}(X),d^i) = \left(\mathrm{Hom}(H_i(X^{i},X^{i-1}),G),D_i^{*} \right)$. The second way to think about it would be to directly take the cohomology of the pair $(X^{i},X^{i-1})$ in $G$ coeffients, that is defining $(C^{i}_{Cell}(X),d^i) = \left((H^{i}(X^{i},X^{i-1};G),\delta^i \circ j_i\right)$, where the coboundary maps are induced by the coboundary maps on the original chain complex

The theorem states that these two ways of defining the cellular cochain complex are isomorphic as co chain complexes. This follows from the universal coefficient theorem